# Git alias output coloring in function

Tags: git, bash, git-alias

I'm tring to add a complex git alias that will echo messages as it performs commands.  I'd like to colorize some of the messages (Red for error, etc).

```
[alias]
    test = !"f() { echo "\033[31mHello\033[0m World"; }; f"
```

However when I execute the alias I get an error:

```
bad config line X in file .gitconfig`
```

Running the same command `echo "\033[31mHello\033[0m World"` in the terminal colorizes just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backslashes have to be escaped. From the git-config docs...

> Inside double quotes, double quote " and backslash \ characters must be escaped: use \" for " and \ for .
>
> The following escape sequences (beside \" and \) are recognized: \n for newline character (NL), \t for horizontal tabulation (HT, TAB) and \b for backspace (BS). ***Other char escape sequences (including octal escape sequences) are invalid.***

This will work.

```
test = !"f() { echo \"\\033[31mHello\\033[0m World\"; }; f"
```

But if your aliases are so complicated that you need to define functions that can turn into a big mess. I'd recommend putting those functions in their own file and sourcing it.

```
test = !"source ~/.gitfuncs; f"

$ cat ~/.gitfuncs
f() { echo "\033[31mHello\033[0m World"; };
```

Comment: I was close, I must have been missing one of the escapes.  I plan to pull it out once I finish working on it - thanks for the info though!